# How to bisect a bib file?

Tags: bibtex

I have one large centrally managed .bib file on my system.  I'm trying to run [betterbib](https://github.com/nschloe/betterbib) on it in order to check the information, but have been getting an error in the process.  In order to improve my error report, I'd like to cut down my bib file to contain only the entries which are creating the problem, but the error output from betterbib doesn't provide any information about which entry is problematic.  I'm thus left with trying to identify the offending entry on my own.  Is there some way (or tool) to efficiently bisect a bib file (split it into two bib files with approximately the same number of entries) so that I can systematically narrow things down to find the offending entry?

Comment: If you don't find such a tool (I don't know one), you might find it surprisingly quick to do it manually. Just split it in two, call the parts `f1.bib` and `f2.bib`, check them, then if the problem is in the latter, split it into `f21.bib` and `f22.bib`, and so on. The power of logarithms at work!

Comment: nelson beebe has created a number of tools for managing bibliographies.  these were [written up in tugboat](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb25-1/beebe-bib.pdf); a web page linking to these and other tools can be found at http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/bibtools.html

Comment: Without knowing more about what makes `betterbib` choke, you might try to typeset the entire `.bib` file and see if you can identify errors that way. A simple `\nocite{*}` along with an unsorted citation style might get you pretty far down the road.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `bibsplit --bynumber` seems to be the most like what I'm looking for, though it can't automatically determine the number which represents half the database.  I can get that information relatively easily from other tools though, so if you'd write up your comment as an answer I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nelson beebe has created a number of tools for managing bibliographies. these were [written up in tugboat](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb25-1/beebe-bib.pdf); a web page linking to these and other tools can be found at http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/bibtools.html.

the author of the question, rpspringuel, reports in a comment that the tool 
 "`bibsplit --bynumber` seems to be the most like what I'm looking for, though it can't automatically determine the number which represents half the database. I can get that information relatively easily from other tools though ..."